# Is there a pattern for this sequence?

Tags: pattern-recognition

I've been looking at this and I thought there might be a pattern but I can't seem to find it. There are always $4$ elements, and they can be divided into $1, 2, 3, 4$ subsets ("chunks"). For example
$$
S = \{ a, b, c, d \}
$$
I want a function with the properties:
\begin{align}
f(1, S) &= \{ \{a, b, c, d \} \} \\
f(2, S) &= \{ \{ a \}, \{ b, c, d \} \} \\
f(3, S) &= \{ \{ a \}, \{ b, c \}, \{ d \} \\
f(4, S) &= \{ \{ a \}, \{ b \}, \{ c \}, \{ d \} \}
\end{align}

I've been looking at it but I can't seem to find a rule that will produce the sequence of lengths. I'm looking for. Any ideas?

Comment: may I ask why? I just need a mathematical rule that will give me those results for that specific input. that fact that will be used in a programming language can be ignored.

Comment: Why doesn't 2 chunks generate $(ab,cd)$

Comment: What would your desired sequences look like if you started with 5 elements?

Comment: @RossMillikan - that's the desired output, it's not a mistake. Would have been a bit easier I guess if it was (ab, cd)

Comment: @mixedmath - at the moment the sequence can have less than 4 elements but not more than 4. So for more than 4 I don't have an issue at the moment.

Comment: You haven't defined the desired output clearly enough.  Do you want all ways to divide the string into $n$ chunks?  Or just one for each size $n$?

Comment: @RossMillikan just one for each size _n_.

Comment: Then which one?  For $m$ elements in the list, there are ${m-1 \choose n}$ choices

Comment: @RossMillikan There are always 4 elements. So I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Why is this question on hold? I don't see how I can be more specific. I've clearly stated what the input is, what the desired output is for a selected number of chunks. The number of sets is always 4. Henning Makholm provided a good answer, but I just need a formula. So which point specifically is not clear enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of imaginable principles that would lead to the partitions you show, but you don't have nearly enough data to choose in a principled way which of them is the once you need in your (undisclosed) application.

For example, if you had 10 elements instead of four, the first few patterns could be

```
abcdefghij
a,bcdefghij
a,bcdefghi,j
a,b,cdefghi,j
a,b,cdefgh,i,j
a,b,c,defgh,i,j
```

or

```
abcdefghij
a,bcdefghij
a,bc,defghij
a,bc,def,ghij
a,b,c,def,ghij
a,b,c,def,ghi,j
```

or even

```
abcdefghij
a,bcdefghij
a,bc,defghij
a,b,c,defghij
a,b,c,de,fghij
a,b,c,d,e,fghij
```

All of these generalize your 4-element division in a relatively straightforward way -- do you have any information that would allow you to judge which of these straightforward ways is *better*?

Comment: I don't think there will be more than 4 elements and I can explain why. This set will contain address parts (street, number, city, county). Like I said before, it can have less, but not more. And this address can be split on 1, 2, 3 or 4 lines (or chunks in my question). I just abstracted the problem thinking it would be easier to find a pattern. So I think the 2nd and 3rd pattern looks compatible. Is there a formula that can be extracted that takes into account the number of chunks and produce the results you've outlined?

Comment: @Max: In that case, "first abcd, then a-bcd, then a-bc-d, then a-b-c-d" is a perfectly cromulent way of expressing the pattern, and trying to shoehorn it into something that looks like there's a "formula" or deeper principle involved would just make it harder to figure out what the code is doing, without giving you any benefit at all over just hardcoding it directly (or using a table).

Comment: Thanks @HenningMakholm. I guess I just needed a confirmation that hardcoding is just as good. For a second I thought there might be a pattern in there.